# Adding numbers together

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to loop over an array whilst addding the numbers together.

Whilst looping over the array, I would like to add the current number to the next.

My array looks like

```
[0,1,0,4,1]
```

I would like to do the following;

```
[0,1,0,4,1] - 0+1= 1, 1+0= 1, 0+4=4, 4+1=5
```

which would then give me `[1,1,4,5]` to do the following; `1+1 = 2, 1+4=5, 4+5=9`

and so on until I get 85.

Could anyone advise on the best way to go about this

Comment: Post the code you've written already.

Comment: I think you can do that in complexity n*log(n)
Please check the divide and conquer algorithm, you can do something similar in concept not in result. You can check this example [link](https://mgechev.github.io/javascript-algorithms/searching_maximum-subarray-divide-and-conquer.js.html)

Comment: If I continue calculating the way you did, the arrays look like {0,1,0,4,1}, {1,1,4,5}, {2,5,9}, {7,14}, {21}; and 85 cannot be reached. Is that correct?

Comment: @tobyUCT - Unless `[2,5,9]` should result in `[7,1,4]`, and then `[8,5]`. Where two digit results are split (`14` becomes `1,4`).

Comment: @j08691 then [8, 5] should  become [13] isn't it ? But then split to [1, 3] and then 4 ?

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question (assuming you want the answer to be 21), but didn't give it an upvote because you showed minimal effort in figuring out the answer on your own...

Answer (score 0):

This transform follows the specified method of summation, but I also get an end result of 21, so please specify how you get to 85.

```
var ary = [0,1,0,4,1],
    transform = function (ary) {
        var length = ary.length;
        return ary.reduce(function (acc, val, index, ary) {
            if (index + 1 !== length) acc.push(ary[index] + ary[index + 1]);
            return acc;
        }, []);
    };
while (ary.length !== 1) ary = transform(ary);
```

Answer (score 0):

The result I get is 21 not 85. This code can be optimised to only use single array. Anyway it gets the job done.

```js
var input = [0, 1, 0, 4, 1];

function calc(input) {
  if (input.length === 1) {
    return input;
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
    result[i] = input[i] + input[i + 1];
  }
  return calc(result);
}

alert(calc(input));
```

This is an O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you do in fact want the answer to be 21 (as it seems like it should be), what you are really trying to do is closely related to the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).
I am not familiar with javascript, so I will write an example in c-style pseudocode:

```
var array = [0,1,0,4,1]
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    int result += array[i] * nChooseK(array.length - 1, i);
}
```

This will put the following numbers into `result` for each respective  iteration:

1. 0 += 0 * 1 --> 0
2. 0 += 1 * 4 --> 4
3. 4 += 0 * 6 --> 4
4. 4 += 4 * 4 --> 20
5. 20 += 1 * 1 --> 21

This avoids all the confusing array operations that arise when trying to iterate through creating shorter-and-shorter arrays; it will also be faster if you have a good nChooseK() implementation.
Now, finding an efficient algorithm for a nChooseK() function is a different matter, but it is a relatively common task so it shouldn't be too difficult (Googling "n choose k algorithm" should work just fine). Some languages even have combinatoric functions in standard math libraries.